# Ошибка: отсутствует роль (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть проверка на наличие роли у пользователя:

```
@commands.has_role(other_staff['admin_role'])
```

И всё хорошо, но мне нужно сделать сообщение ошибки, если у пользователя *нету* такой роли.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через [декоратор](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html)

```
def is_role():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='айди роли') in ctx.author.roles
    return commands.check(predicate)

@commands.command()
@is_role
async def test(self, ctx):
    pass
```